# AngularJS: single select between multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to force a single-selection on checkboxes, similar to a html "select"

I have a html simple table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="subscription in entities">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isChecked(subscription)" ng-click="toggleSelection(subscription)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then I have some simple controller functions for those directives above:

```
$scope.isChecked = function(entity) {
    return $scope.checkedEntity === entity;
};

$scope.toggleSelection = function(entity) {
    entity.checked = !entity.checked;
    if (entity.checked) {
        $scope.checkedEntity = entity;
    } else {
        $scope.checkedEntity = null;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, and I think I just discovered why.... the ng-click has 0 priority, vs 100 for ng-checked.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: can you share your `$scope` objects

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean?

Comment: why not just use type="radio"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bind `ng-model` to `subscription.checked`, and have `ng-click` uncheck all subscriptions except the one clicked.  Since these are checkboxes, the one clicked will toggle itself.

```
<tr ng-repeat="subscription in entities">
  <td>
    <input ng-model="subscription.checked" ng-click="updateSelection($index, entities)" type="checkbox" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

You can use a plain `for` loop, but [angular's `forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) allows us to alias each item as `subscription` and improve readability:

```
$scope.updateSelection = function(position, entities) {
  angular.forEach(entities, function(subscription, index) {
    if (position != index) 
      subscription.checked = false;
  });
}
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/XD7r6PoTWpI4cBjdIZtv?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Interesting, I originally tried a tiny variation of that where I only pass the current entity on ng-click, and the function iterates over the $scope.entities which should be the same data structure... but for some reason yours works and mine doesn't!

Comment: This syntax is nicer :P `entities.map((x, i) => x.checked = position === i);`

Comment: Great help Thanks, alot!

Comment: Hey i have simple layout but instead of checkboxes, i have divs. How to add the active class with same logic.? Only one div should get active class and also on click of active div, it should toggle its class

Answer (score 8):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('appc', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.selected = 'other';
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appc">
  <label>SELECTED: {{selected}}</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='male'" ng-true-value="'male'" ng-model="selected">Male
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='female'" ng-true-value="'female'" ng-model="selected">Female
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='other'" ng-true-value="'other'" ng-model="selected">Other
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code to achieve the similar functionality. Trick is to use *ng-click* which can yield this pretty nicely. *checkbox-1 & checkbox-2* are boolean in nature.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkbox-2 = false" ng-model="checkbox-1" >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkbox-1 = false" ng-model="checkbox-2" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd suggest one of three options for you.

1. Write a directive that will set up the checkboxes for you and manage the state within them. This isn't ideal, because you're turning a rule about your model (only one subscription should be checked) into DOM manipulation problem.
2. Structure your model such that only one subscription is ever marked active. This is tricky, because modifying the model on a change will kick off another digest cycle, not what you want.
3. Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes. That will get you the modality you want. :-P

I'd go with option 3--I'm always a fan of taking advantage of native input elements.

```
<tr ng-repeat="subscription in entities">
<td><input type="radio"
   ng-model="selection"
   name="subscriptionRadio"
   value="{{subscription}}"/>
</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: For 1) agreed, unpleasant. For 3) Right! I had a big argument with the UX designer about UI standards dating back not simply years but over a decade, but sadly it MUST be checkboxes... *fist shaking*
For #2, I tried originaly with a ng-model tied to the subscription, and then a ng-changed that would then update the model across all the subscriptions. But in this case, the model was updated, but the "checked" state didn't change, unless I used jquery, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: What you can do is set up the directive such that it triggers on the model change and reconfigures the checkboxes. "two-way" binding is definitely a thing in Angular directives, and it might help you out here.

Comment: Also, I figured you would have gone with radio buttons if you could have. ;)